# Reduce size of chart within the canvas

Tags: javascript, canvas, chart.js

I have done a lot of reading this afternoon about reducing the canvas size of chart.js charts and can see that it comes with issues. What I would like to know is *whether its possible to reduce the size of the actual graph within the canvas*? The size of the canvas isn't the problem as I have an aspectRatio of 1 which causes the (radar) chart to be square in aspect ratio. What I would like is to reduce the size of the chart to say 80% of its calculated size. Anyone know if this is possible? Am happy to hack the code as I've had to already for other features.

Comment: Use two canvas, one the size you want your chart to be, the other with the other content you want to display. This has a number of bonuses too, being able to redraw your main canvas without having to redraw the chart too, or the other way around, helping you get better performance.

Comment: But you can't use % sizes for initialising chart.js. If you could provide a working example that would be great?

Comment: Compute the percentages yourself. If the chart is full width then just compute `.8 *  window.innerWidth`, which is 80% of the window width, just for example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that is possible.

You can set **padding** for your chart layout accordingly, which will decrease the actual chart size, like so :

```
layout: {
   padding: 20
}
```

set this inside your chart­*'s* options config.

Comment: Super simple answer! Thanks.